# ¿Cómo validar un archivo CSV de excel al subirlo en PHP a BD MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv

Tengo un problema y necesito de su amabilidad. Agradezco de antemano.
Planteo lo siguiente:
Encontré un script que me permite subir un archivo a una base de datos utilizando un archivo de Excel en CSV. El script funciona de maravilla, pero, suceden ciertas cosas que menciono a continuación:
Imagina que tengo 2 archivos en formato CSV:
* cliente1.csv
* cliente2.csv
Imaginen que el archivo cliente1.csv tiene 9 columnas y el archivo PHP esta listo,configurado y funciona de maravilla para recibir estrictamente las 9 columnas ok?. Perfecto. Ahora imaginen que accidentalmente subo el archivo cliente2.csv que tiene 5 columnas. Cuando intento subir el archivo recibo 4 errores:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in D:\xampp\htdocs\app\cliente.php on line 44
Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in D:\xampp\htdocs\app\cliente.php on line 45
Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in D:\xampp\htdocs\app\cliente.php on line 46
Notice: Undefined offset: 11 in D:\xampp\htdocs\app\cliente.php on line 47
```

Yo entiendo que recibo estos errores por que necesito enviar 9 registros y estoy enviando accidentalmente 5.
La pregunta sería, ¿Cómo puedo hacer o que me recomendarían hacer para validar esa subida de archivo en donde me muestre un mensaje diciendo que El archivo no es el correcto?

Les comparto a continuación el código:

```
cliente.php //Nombre del archivo
<php? require_once "clases/conexion.php"; //Esta es la conexión.
$obj= new conectar(); //Esta es la conexión.
$conexion=$obj->conexion(); //Esta es la conexión.
$message = ''; //Esto es para el mensaje de confirmación.
if(isset($_POST["upload"])){
 if($_FILES['product_file']['name']){
  $filename = explode(".", $_FILES['product_file']['name']);
  if(end($filename) == "csv"){
   $handle = fopen($_FILES['product_file']['tmp_name'], "r");

   while($data = fgetcsv($handle)){
    $codigo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $data[0]);
    $nombres = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $data[1]);  
    $apellidos = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $data[2]);
    $direccion = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $data[3]);
    $telefono = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $data[4]);
    $correo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $data[5]);
    $contrasena = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $data[6]);
    $tipo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $data[7]);
    $estado = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $data[8]);
    $query = "
     UPDATE clientes 
     SET nombres = '$nombres', 
     apellidos = '$apellidos', 
     direccion = '$direccion',
     telefono = '$telefono', 
     correo = '$correo',
     contra = '$contrasena',
     tipo = '$tipo',
     estado = '$estado'
     WHERE codigo = '$codigo'";
    mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
  }
   fclose($handle);
   header("location: cliente.php?updation=1");
  }else{
   $message = 'Solo archivos CSV';
  }
 }else{
  $message = 'No selecciono un archivo';
 }
}
if(isset($_GET["updation"])){
 $message = 'Se subio el archivo correctamente';
}
?>
```

El siguiente código HTML es el del formulario que envia el POST upload.

```
                <form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                <input type="file" name="product_file" />
                <button type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" value="Upload"><i class="fas fa-upload"></i> SUBIR</button>
                </form>
```

Agradezco de antemano el conocmiento y ayuda que me puedan aportar. Saludos

Comment: En base a tu código, una opción que podrías aplicar es validar que todos los datos son distinto de vacío.

Comment: Puedes utilizar explode() para separar el nombre de la extension y validar que si es distinto de xls no permita subirlo